# User Information when using external authentication in ASP .NET MVC 4

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, linkedin-api

I am using ASP .NET MVC and I have been successfully able to login using LinkedIn and Facebook. But inside ExternalLoginCallback() action, I have failed to retrieve user email when I login using LinkedIn (although I am getting other info like user name, job title etc)

Similarly with Facebook, I am not getting fields like job title in response.

Can anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link -  http://mvcrocksonasp.net/OAuthWithMVC4 here is code for getting user information via linkedin, Its working fine.